# Link to static library by cmake

Tags: c++, cmake, numa

I have a project C++ using libnuma library. Because I don't have permission to install libnuma in the root system, so I have to install it in folder of user: /home/khangtg/opt. This folder contains 2 main folders:

- Folder **include** contains: numacompat1.h, numa.h, numaif.h
- Folder **lib** contains: libnuma.a, libnuma.la, libnuma.so, libnuma.so.1, libnuma.so.1.0.0

Now, I have a file .cpp include libnuma library:

```
#include <numa.h>
```

and I build the project by file CMakeLists.txt with content:

```
add_library (common Bigraph.cpp AdjList.cpp Vocab.cpp NumaArray.cpp clock.cpp)
set (LINK_LIBS ${LINK_LIBS} common gflags numa )

add_executable (warplda main.cpp lda.cpp warplda.cpp)
add_executable (format format.cpp)

target_link_libraries (warplda ${LINK_LIBS})
target_link_libraries (format ${LINK_LIBS})
```

After run cmake command, I get some error that is "can not include numa.h".

So, how can I fix this error and build the project by cmake. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you want to set the `link_directories` to include the directory of the libraries. More can be found [in the cmake docs](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/link_directories.html). This tells the linker where to look for the libraries.

It should probably look something like this

```
link_directories(/home/khangtg/opt/lib)
```

Also add the include directories command from [this documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/include_directories.html).
This will look like this

```
include_directories(/home/khangtg/opt/include)
```

Comment: you also need to add the include_director for headers this will be `include_directories(/home/khangtg/opt/include)`

Answer (score 0):

This might be useful to add to your cmake build file:

```
include_directories("/home/khangtg/opt/include")
```

From: [cmake tutorial](https://cmake.org/cmake-tutorial/)

You may also want to change the include to :

```
#include "numa.h"
```

Comment: It actually fixes the error include, but I see the other error here: 
    /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lnuma.
    collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status.
    make[2]: *** [src/format] Error 1.
    make[1]: *** [src/CMakeFiles/format.dir/all] Error 2.
    make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....